# Do moderators have the right to force their edits on my questions?

Tags: discussion, editing

Do moderators have the right to force their edits on my questions in excuse of " improving the question" even if I am not happy with them and is there some tool here that helps stopping moderators/users from editing my questions?

Comment: Is there an example of your Question being edited in a way you object to?  Have you familiarized yourself with `MarkDown` and $\LaTeX$ syntax, so you can make the improvements you want?  Moderators have a limited amount of time to spend fixing poor grammar and formatting.  Such fixes are ordinarily left to the user community, and of course you could resort to rollback edits or deleting your post if the model of cooperative edits is not agreeable to you.  The cumulative effect of poorly received Questions would be an automated ban on posting them, so weigh carefully what you try to do.

Comment: @hardmath I guess they are referring to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4351955/is-sum-j-1-infty-sum-n-1-infty-left-frace-j-nn2-frace-n-j), edit 3 and 4 by me and Xander respectively. Started from this [chat post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60185104#60185104). In general I agree with you that moderators don't go out and do tones of edits.

Comment: @hardmath they just edit it the way they like and OPS can do nothing about it and if you argue with them, you most likely get suspended. I got suspended for 4 times so far and for absurd reasons. See the edit history of my question here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4351955

Comment: Voting on meta is significantly different than voting on the main site.  Downvotes often indicate disagreement with policy positions, rather than disapproval of the research or presentation than went into a post.  I have no insight into anything other than your current suspended status; the moderators do not discuss anything openly about that except with you.  I appreciate your extensive mathematical contributions, and agree with the part of your post that said we should focus on the math.  For that reason I try not to take disagreements on math personally.

Comment: @hardmath thank you for the kind words.

Comment: @hardmath I, also, agree with the statement that we should focus on mathematics.  Which is exactly *why* that statement was removed.  It is not a mathematical statement, and *removes* focus from the mathematics.  Meta-commentary does not belong in posts, period.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, every user can edit every post on the site (with the exception of those banned from suggesting edits after numerous rejected edit suggestions). The moderators can lock a post, making it impossible to edit it further, which we do on occasion when there is an edit war.

This is one of the key features of the SE platform, being a collaborative Q&A platform.

That being said, if the changes are minor, stylistic (do note, basic $\rm\LaTeX$ edits are *not* considered stylistic), or otherwise "too major", it is common to let the person who made the original posting make the call, since it is still their voice. But do note that it is very easy as the author to feel that any kind of change is too minor or too major, even if this is not always the case.

Comment: Of course every user can edit any question on the site but I am asking if mods have the right to FORCE their edits on questions. Let me give you this example math.stackexchange.com/q/4351955. Here the mod Xander Henderson keeps editing the way I wrote the equations after I told him I don't like his edit.

Comment: @AliShadhar The issue is very simple: ```\text{}``` does not properly linewrap, so the text flows into the sidebars for people with narrow displays (or large text), creating bothersome sliders and making your post hard to read. I am sure your goal is *not* to make your post hard to read or unreadable to some users.

Comment: @pedro Tamaroff he could have said so from the first time he edited it but he kept using rollback without saying anything. Thanks.